# c# convert decimal to comma separated string

Tags: c#

I want to convert decimal to comma separated string for INR currency

```
1.59 => 1.59
11.59 => 11.59
111.59 => 111.59
1111.59 => 1,111.59
11111.59 => 11,111.59
111111.59 => 1,11,111.59
1111111.59 => 11,11,111.59
11111111.59 => 1,11,11,111.59
111111111.59 => 11,11,11,111.59
1111111111.59 => 111,11,11,111.59
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: `decimalVariable.ToString("#,###.00");`?

Comment: @juharr He groups by 2 and 3... I think it is an indian-style grouping.

Comment: @xanatos Wow, didn't even notice the grouping to begin with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
decimal input = 1111111111.59m;
string result = input.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("EN-in"));
```

- `"C"` is used to [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) to Currency
- `"EN-in"` sets the **En**glish-**in**dian culture

example https://dotnetfiddle.net/PL4yT8

Comment: how do i remove trailiing 0s in this? if input is 111.00, i want output as 111

Comment: @sahil `C0` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx